# How to refresh or reload a background image not the whole webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an animated gif that plays spinning gears for 1 second, then stops. I have a static image that loads first and is replaced by the gif when it is clicked so the gears spin. This is done using css and javascript, see code below. It works as intended on the first click but the gif animation does not play on the second click unless the page is refreshed. I don’t want to refresh the whole page as I am using the animated give to display a div below the gears when it is clicked.  The gif is placed as a background image. Is it possible to just reload or refresh the gif background image/gif when clicked?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    <style>
        #gear-box{
            height: 80x;
            width: 50;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .turngears{
        width: 80px;
            height: 50px;
            background: url('image/GearsBaseStatic.png') no-repeat; 
        }
        
        .spingears{
            width: 80px;
            height: 50px;
            background: url('image/GearsBase.gif') no-repeat;
            background-size:74px 45px;
            
        }
        
    </style>
<body>

    <div id="gear-box">
    <div id="gears" class="turngears">
    </div>
        
    </div>
<div>

    <script>
    var gear = document.getElementById('gears');
        
        gear.addEventListener('click',function(gear){
            gear.target.classList.toggle('spingears')
        })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/roeducmk/ lookslike your code is working with gif

Comment: @Hemakumar, thanks for your input, however it looks like your gif is a constant loop. My gif is designed to stop after 1 second which is what I want. But then I want it to restart and run again on the next click, but the gif does not replay unless the page is refreshed. Somehow, I want to restart the gif without refreshing the page. Thanks again for looking.

Comment: Update my JSFiddle with your gif and share the link, So I can help you with that. @f1inshot

Comment: @Hemakumar thanks for your help the solution from @A Haworth works very well. I wasn't sure how to upload images to jsFiddle but I will look into that for possible future use. Thanks again for helping. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a reload of just the gif by adding a parameter to the end of the url which changes each time.

In this snippet the background image url has a ?update= added. On each click an extra character is added to it which will force the browser to get another copy of the image when that class is used. A more sophisticated version would add a digit 1 so we don't end up with huge string of characters, but whether that matters depends on the use case - how many clicks are likely.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    <style id="gearstyle">
        #gear-box{
            height: 80x;
            width: 50;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .turngears{
        width: 80px;
            height: 50px;
            background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/noWxL.jpg') no-repeat; 
        }
        
        .spingears{
            width: 80px;
            height: 50px;
            background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewreb.giff?update=1') no-repeat;
            background-size:74px 45px;           
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="gear-box">
    <div id="gears" class="turngears">
    </div>    
  </div>
<div>
<script>
let gears = document.getElementById('gears');
let gearStyle = document.getElementById('gearstyle');
gears.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  gears.classList.toggle('spingears');
  gearStyle.innerHTML = gearStyle.innerHTML.replace('?update=','?update=1'); //puts another character onto the version string
})
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: @A Haworth, thanks for your solution, it works brilliantly. It will be clicked on a lot, so when you say a more sophisticated version would be to add a digit 1, is that (gif?update=1) as shown in your solution. Thanks again for your help. Regards

Comment: Glad it worked. Yes, at the moment I rather lazily just put an extra character in the query string because it was trivial to do. You could either get Javascript to create a random number to put in there instead (Math.random()) or keep a count yourself of clicks and put that number in after the ?v= TBH I'm not absolutely sure that just having a ?v=1 there might not be enough for some browsers to make them fetch the image again, but I don't know so erred on the safe side.

Comment: @ A Haworth, thanks for the update I have changed the code to random number as you suggested. I notice either way with Firefox if refresh is pressed the animation does not replay. Edge and Chrome are fine, any ideas would be welcome, thanks again for your help. Regards

Comment: @ A Haworth, please ignore that last question, this only appears to happen on Firefox when using a local testing server. Thanks